# Derivative of expected value of a function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, optimization, expectation, maxima-minima

Suppose we have the following general problem:

$$ \max_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_{x} \big[ f(x, \theta) \big]$$

where $f(x, \theta)$ is continuously differentiable and bounded in $\theta$. Assume that $\mathbb{E}_{x} \big[ f(x, \theta) \big]$ has no closed-form solution due to the distribution of the random variable $x$, but is known to be concave.

I would like to know under which conditions I can solve the above problem by taking the derivative inside the expectation and set it to zero, i.e.,

$$\mathbb{E}_{x} \bigg[ \frac{d}{d \theta} f(x, \theta) \bigg] = 0.$$

Comment: You can always do that since the expectation operator is an integral not over $\theta$, but over $x$. But the expression is only meaningful when $f$ is differentiable w.r.t. $\theta$

Comment: @Mathemagical if you're referring to when you can interchange the operations—Leibniz's rule—then there actually are some conditions that need to be satisfied by $f: \Omega \times A \to \mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is an open subset of the real line—namely that $f(\omega, t)$ is integrable for each $t\in A$, that for all almost all $\omega$, the partial of $f$ with respect to $t$ exists, and lastly,  $f$ is dominated by an integrable function $g(\omega)$ for all $t\in A$.

Comment: So if $f$ satisfies these properties, I should be able to write $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} \mathbb{E}_{x} \big[ f(x, \theta) \big] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \theta} f(t, \theta) \phi_{x}(t) \mathrm{d} t$, with $\phi_{x}(t)$ being the pdf of the random variable $x$. Right?

Comment: @ItaAtz that's right.